# Any UI controls out there that implement the YUI Progress Bar Pattern?

Tags: jquery, yui

I'm looking for a control (any web technology - jquery, css, html, etc.) that implements the Progress Bar Pattern as shown in the YUI Patterns site (http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/navigation/bar/progress.html).

I know this is very simple and I can build one if it doesn't exist but I am having a hard time finding one and it is so common that I am sure there is something out there.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like [jBreadCrumb](http://www.comparenetworks.com/developers/jqueryplugins/jbreadcrumb.html) or [xBreadCrumbs](http://www.ajaxblender.com/script-sources/xbreadcrumbs/demo/index.html)?

And in case you need this progress bar for a form wizard, there are plugins for that as well: [jQuery Form Wizard](http://thecodemine.org/) and [this one](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex16/formwizard.htm) (which might be the same one with a different theme)